# Installing Socket.io package in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

1) Installed **Node v0.10.13 X64**(I am in Win 8)

2) Opened **CMD** with **Administrator** Priveleges

3) Typed `npm install socket.io` it downloads something but it **shows something like a build error at the end**.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
unbuild socket.io@0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-0.9.
16.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/-/base64id-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/-/policyfile-0.0.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.4.2.tg
z
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/-/active-x-obfuscato
r-0.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/-/xmlhttprequest-1.4.2.tg
z
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-1.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/-/active-x-obfuscato
r-0.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor

>ws@0.4.27 install C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\sock
et.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_mo
dules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\
node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: build/binding.sln
socket.io@0.9.16 node_modules\socket.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.7.3
└── socket.io-client@0.9.16 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obf
uscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.27)
```

I also tried below commands from some blogs but don't know what it means neither it doesn't work.

**1) npm install express**

**2) npm install jade**

**3) npm install -g node -gyp**

I am trying to install from morning couldn't find a solution.Please help me out.

Comment: Not related but I noticed you are installing modules into your C:\Windows\system32 folder. So can you try some other place, to rule out access problems.

Comment: I tried that too...
> ws@0.4.27 install c:\wamp\www\test\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.
io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


c:\wamp\www\test\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modul
es\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

Comment: Make sure you have all the prerequisite software required. See https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: The failure is on the required-component "ws" which has an open issue for this error: https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/240

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508507/41153) run your shell as administrator, and this problem should go away.

Comment: it does not (node-v0.12.7-x64.msi / python-2.7.10.amd64)